# How to update a docker image with out the docker file?

Tags: docker

I have build some docker image, and run it (ubuntu 14).
Now, I am installing new software into the container. 
Can I save a snapshot of the container, or must I update the docker file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can commit the image using `docker commit <container-name> <target-image-name>`

This will create a new image that is a snaphsot of the container running.

**Note however**, changes made inside volumes will not be commited as part of the image.
You need to backup the volumes of the running container and move them incase you want to run the image on a new machine.

Comment: What do you mean by volumes? What are the changes that will be kept and what are the ones which won't be kept?

Comment: check https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/#extended-description for more info. Basically if you are mounting a volume over a directory in the container, changes that are made to that directory are not commited inside the image.

Comment: And changes which are not on a mounted folder are kept?

Comment: @avitheavi yes other changes are commited inside the image.

Comment: is there a possibility to auto-commit when exitiing the container?

Answer (score 0):

You can commit container changes to create an image using `docker commit` -

- Syntax

`docker commit [OPTIONS] CONTAINER [REPOSITORY[:TAG]]`

- Example -

`docker commit abf279d17e0w  viveky4d4v/ubuntu:v2`

- View your new image -

`docker images`

Answer (score 0):

Once you

`docker commit`

you can use the dockerfile-from-image on your commited image,

https://hub.docker.com/r/dduvnjak/dockerfile-from-image/

(as https://github.com/CenturyLinkLabs/dockerfile-from-image is broken)

It should show an updated Dockerfile